# CGPoint Make not positioning UIView correctly

Tags: ios, swift

Im working on a basic application and for some reason i can't center the view (textBox) with CGPointMake. I know that    textBox.center=self.view.center; will center the view but i dont know why the CGPointMake is not working. I'm using Swift.

```
    textBox.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15)
    textBox.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.Default
    textBox.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    CGPointMake(187.5, 333.5)
    textBox.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Done
    self.view.addSubview(textBox)
```

Comment: `CGPointMake(187.5, 333.5)` is not assigned to any property of the textBox. Are you sure ?

Answer (score -1):

You Make the point by this code

`CGPointMake(187.5, 333.5)`
But You didn't assign the center of textBox to this point . 
So use this code

```
textBox.center = CGPointMake(187.5, 333.5);
```